# How can I split a String based on capitalization scheme?

Tags: java, regex

I have a String that I've retrieved from conventions set by `get` methods. Something like `getMyObject` which becomes `MyObject`. I want to make this String presentable to the user so "My Object". However, I also want to account for acronyms that could occur within the object name, so something like `getFBILicense` should become "FBI License". I'm a little stuck on how to do this with regex.

```
(?=\\p{Upper}+\\p{Lower})
```

The above feels like what I'm after, and yet it's not quite right, this breaks for the simple example "thisIsMMyStringValue" which becomes `this` `is` `M` `My` `String` `Value`. I think this error makes sense to me, as both `M` and `My` are an uppercase with 0 or more uppercases between them and the first lowercase they encounter. However, I am not sure how to address this using regex so that the returned value is instead `this` `is` `MMy` `String` `Value`

EDIT: I am using Java's `String::split` method with the regex in question.

Comment: Forward lookup to see if the next letter is also capitalized would work, have you tried that?

Comment: It looks like your code is right; your example 'getFBILicense' produces 'FBI License' - this is the same as with 'MMy' becoming 'M' and 'My'. What's wrong with that? If you were to get 'MMy' from 'MMy' then you are breaking your acronym rule because there's a lowercase in it..

Comment: You correctly pointed out that MMy is not a good example, however `FBILicense` returns `F` `B` `I` `License` under the given conditions.

Comment: See the linked question, this (atrocity) works: `(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])|(?<=[A-Z])(?=[A-Z][a-z])`

Comment: The atrocity does indeed work

Comment: What if method name is `getMyName1Name2Name3` should that not be translated to `My Name1 Name2 Name3`?